# Some odd wiring in my breaker box. Is this up to code?

Tags: wiring, electrical-panel, code-compliance

I'm poking around in my breaker box and I notice a white wire screwed into the ground bus. Tracing it back, both bare and white are on the ground bus and the black is screwed into a breaker. **Is this up to code?**

This circuit is connected to an RV plug.

---

Secondly, I also notice a bare wire screwed into the neutral bus. As far as I can tell this is 14-3 Romex with bare & white to the neutral bus and black & red to different breakers. **Is this up to code?**

---

Both of these circuits are additions by the previous owner.

Comment: The two hot wires of the 14-3 are supposed to be on a 2-pole breaker with a link between the two manual shut-offs so that the two breakers are switched together. The problem with using two independent 1-pole breakers is that two 1-pole breakers could be placed on the same leg and so lead to overloading the shared neutral.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally neutral and ground are bonded at your main panel, but must not be bonded at any subpanels downstream.  So mixing neutrals and grounds on the same bar is OK in the main panel but not at subpanels.

The 14/3 with black and red on two breakers and white on the neutral bar - that's a multiwire branch circuit with a shared neutral.  When installed properly this is code compliant.  However take particular care when working on and around this circuit, if the neutral is disconnected it can result in an overvoltage on the affected circuits.